# How to upgrade module Suggest a Frend from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, or how to replace it?

Tags: drupal-modules

I am creating a social networking site for which I need the module [Suggest a Friend](https://www.drupal.org/project/suggest_a_friend). But this module is not available for Drupal 7 (yet), only for Drupal 6.

Is there any module which can be used as a replacement of the Suggest a Friend module (for Drupal 7). Or how can we upgrade a Drupal 6 module to Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the api changes from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 and look up the functions/objects that are used:

http://drupal.org/node/224333